# Получение длины генератора без распаковки

Tags: python, python-3.x

Есть следующий код, выборки данных из БД, проблема заключается в том, что для установления максимального значения progressBar'a(PyQt5) приходиться дважды делать запрос в БД. Один раз для получения как раз таки длины возвращаемого генератора, а второй раз для показа данных в tableWidjet. Есть ли способ получить длину генератора, без такого костыля?

Код прилагаю:

```
    elif (self.params[0] != '(не выбрано)' and self.params[1] != '(не выбрано)' and self.params[2] == '(не выбрано)' 
          and self.params[3] == '(не выбрано)' and self.params[4] == '' and self.params[5] == '(не выбрано)'):
        
        self.progress_bar_value = 0
        self.ui.progressBar.setValue(self.progress_bar_value)
        #Chfysq костыль для прогрессбара
        self.cursor.execute('''SELECT * FROM SomethingTable WHERE something_param_1=:something_param_1 
                                                              AND something_param_2=:something_param_2''',
                            {'something_param_1':self.ui.comboBoxSomething_param_1.currentText(),
                             'something_param_2':self.ui.comboBoxsomething_param_2.currentText()})  
        self.ui.progressBar.setMaximum(len(self.cursor.fetchall()))
        
        self.cursor.execute('''SELECT * FROM SomethingTable WHERE something_param_1=:something_param_1 
                                                              AND something_param_2=:something_param_2''',
                            {'something_param_1':self.ui.comboBoxSomething_param_1.currentText(),
                             'something_param_2':self.ui.comboBoxsomething_param_2.currentText()})          
        
        self.ui.tableSqlWidget.setRowCount(0)
        for row, form in enumerate(self.cursor):

            self.ui.tableSqlWidget.insertRow(row)
            self.progress_bar_value += 1
            self.ui.progressBar.setValue(self.progress_bar_value)  
            for column, item in enumerate(form):
                self.ui.tableSqlWidget.setItem(row, column, QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(str(item)))
                self.ui.tableSqlWidget.resizeColumnsToContents()
                self.ui.tableSqlWidget.setColumnWidth(0, 30)               
            QtWidgets.qApp.processEvents()
```

Comment: У генераторов нет длины. Придётся получить из него все данные, например с помощью преобразования его в список, измерить длину списка и работать дальше с ним. Но этот вариант допустим, если объёмы выбираемых из БД данных существенно меньше объёмов доступной оперативной памяти.

Comment: спасибо за ответ, то есть придется действовать таким методом... Тогда лучше делать через len(list(self.cursor)) или как сейчас через fetchall? объемы извлекаемой информации порядка до 500 записей

Comment: Что-нибудь вроде `data = list(cursor.fetchall())` и потом `len(data)` и `for row, form in enumerate(data):` чтобы два раза в базу не ходить.

Comment: @vladuxa_23, а вы средствами базы узнайте размер таблицы. Сделайте запрос ваш запрос, но с `count`: `SELECT count(*) FROM ...`, тогда получите количество строк

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если позволяет конкретный модуль DB клиента, то можно использовать:

```
row_count = self.cursor.execute('''SELECT * FROM SomethingTable''')
```

Или

```
self.cursor.execute('''SELECT * FROM SomethingTable''')
row_count = self.cursor.rowcount
```

---

[PEP 249](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/) Python Database API Specification v2.0:

> Cursor Objects should respond to the following methods and attributes:

[…]

> [**`.rowcount`**](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/#rowcount)
>  
>              This read-only attribute specifies the number of rows that the last .execute*() produced (for DQL statements like 'select') or affected (for DML statements like 'update' or 'insert').

Следует, однако, иметь в виду, что `rowcount` может в некоторых случаях считаться динамически и быть доступен только после первого fetch, или быть недоступен совсем:

> The attribute is -1 in case no [`.execute*()`](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/#id14) has been performed on the cursor or the rowcount of the last operation is cannot be determined by the interface. [[7]](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/#id46)
>
> **Note:**
>   Future versions of the DB API specification could redefine the latter case to have the object return `None` instead of -1.

---

> [7]   The rowcount attribute may be coded in a way that updates its value dynamically. This can be useful for databases that return usable rowcount values only after the first call to a .fetch*() method.